# Why i am getting "The getter 'values' isn't defined for the type 'Object'" error in hive flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a page where i can save my Marked as favorite item via hive.But i am getting some error as "The getter 'values' isn't defined for the type 'Object'".How can i solve this issue?.The problem is in the ***List post = box?.values ?? [];*** line

```
class FavoritesPage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
appBar:AppBar(
  title: Text("My favorite quotes"),
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,),
  body: ValueListenableBuilder(
    
    valueListenable: Hive.box(FAVORITES_BOX).listenable(),
    builder:(context,box,child) {
      List post = box?.values ?? [];
      return ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        children:<Widget> [
          ...post.map(
              (p) => ListTile(
                title: Text(p["title"]),
              )
          )
        ],

      );
    }

   )

   );}
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a type argument to your `ValueListenableBuilder`. I'm not sure which type exactly, it depends on whatever type `Hive.box(FAVORITES_BOX).listenable()` evaluates to.

---

Here is a simple example copied directly from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  final Widget goodJob = const Text('Good job!');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title)
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget? child) {
                // This builder will only get called when the _counter
                // is updated.
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('$value'),
                    child!,
                  ],
                );
              },
              valueListenable: _counter,
              // The child parameter is most helpful if the child is
              // expensive to build and does not depend on the value from
              // the notifier.
              child: goodJob,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.plus_one),
        onPressed: () => _counter.value += 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The relevant part of the code is here:

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
  ...
  valueListenable: _counter,
  ...
)
```

Notice that the `ValueListenableBuilder` has a type argument of `int`, as in `ValueListenableBuilder<int>`. The type argument should match up with the value passed into the `valueListenable` argument. In this case `_counter` is passed in which is of type `ValueNotifier<int>`. They have matching type arguments of type `int`.

You need to add to your `ValueListenableBuilder` a type argument, which matches the type argument of whatever type `Hive.box(FAVORITES_BOX).listenable()` evaluates to.

In other words if `Hive.box(FAVORITES_BOX).listenable()` is of type `ValueNotifier<String>` then you should have a `ValueListenableBuilder<String>`. If it is of type `ValueNotifier<bool>` then you should have a `ValueListenableBuilder<bool>`. If it is of type `ValueNotifier<Spongebob>` then you should have a `ValueListenableBuilder<Spongebob>` etc...

Comment: can you provide a simple example? @mmcdon20

Comment: @Arefin added example.